# Angular path, query and hash routing combined

Tags: angular, angular-router

I would like my app to have URL as this 
`https://example.com/rootFolder/child/other?page=1&sort=-name#lightbox/{fileID}**`

I have tried this router, but I seem not to be able to do match any hash parts.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'root',
        pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
        path: '#/lightbox/:fileID',
        component: LightBoxComponent,
        outlet: 'light-box',
    },
    {
        matcher: lightBoxMatcher,
        component: LightBoxComponent,
        outlet: 'light-box',
    },
    {
        matcher: folderMatcher, // Matches any depth of folders
        component: MainComponent,
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
            onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
            scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
            paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always',
            //enableTracing: true,
        }),
    ],
    ...
});
```

Comment: Why don't you make the url /{folderID}?page=1&sort=-name&lightboxFileId={fileID}?

Comment: I have no idea how to combine path with query and hash together

Comment: So apparently angular team does not recognise a something user may want, thus it is not implemented. However, there should be an API to implement custom (part of) router to handle this... (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29833#issuecomment-492436973)